# GraphQL error: Field error: value is not an instance of Date

Tags: redis, graphql, apollo

After I've installed `redis-server` and `graphql-redis-subscriptions` I receive the following error `[GraphQL error]: Message: Field error: value is not an instance of Date, Location: [object Object], Path: messageAdded,createdAt [Error: GraphQL error: Field error: value is not an instance of Date]` If I remove `createdAt` from query everything works fine.

`scalar Date` I am using in types schema